# Disk usage command problem

Tags: linux, disk-usage, command, output

I used

```
du -h hello
```

where `hello` is a file or directory name. It printed

```
4.0k hello
```

in output. I don't need the output to contain the `.0k` part. How can I remove that so that the output is just `4 hello`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

```
$ du -h ### Human format
$ du -m ### Show output size in one-megabyte
$ du -k ### Show output size in one-kilobyte
```

The `-k` option has `du` echo

```
4    hello
```

Comment: du -k contest is the correct